# Who is that at the end of "The Doctor Falls"?

Tags: doctor-who

[Yeah, if you haven't seen the season 10 finale, don't go reading this question, right?]

This is probably supposed to be obvious, but who is that at the very end of the *The Doctor Falls*? Both in-universe and out, if you could, because part of my confusion is the out-of-universe fact that, as far as I know,

> the actor who played the first Doctor died a long time ago.

Comment: The First Doctor has been portrayed by another actor in at least one past multi-Doctor crossover event (Richard Hurndall in "The Five Doctors"), so I assume they're simply doing that again.

Comment: Yep, it's not that uncommon. The Sixth Doctor was also played by another actor at one point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### It's actor **David Bradley**

[image]

> David Bradley appeared as the "original" Doctor in the closing moments of the episode, as Capaldi's Doctor struggled to resist his own impending regeneration. 
>   It confirms what some had already speculated: that this year's Christmas special will be a multi-Doctor adventure, with the story of this remarkable reunion continuing in December.
>
> ...
>
> Bradley of course steps in to the role originally played by William Hartnell – Bradley previously played Hartnell in BBC2 Who origin story [An Adventure in Space and Time](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2017-07-01/remembering-the-real-bill-and-heather-in-unseen-photos-of-doctor-whos-david-bradley-and-lesley-manville) in 2013.
>
> [RadioTimes](http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2017-07-02/new-doctor-who-christmas-special-pictures-tease-history-making-reunion-for-peter-capaldis-doctor)

Comment: He was also in the Dinosaurs on a Spaceship episode of Who as the villain and he played Filch in Harry Potter.